# col-xs-* not working when mobile is orienting between horizontal/vertical view in bootstrap 3

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, landscape-portrait

I'm having a problem in Bootstrap 3 in using col-xs-* for mobile devices..

I'm using below code for mobile..

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"> div content 1 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"> div content 2 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"> div content 3 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"> div content 4 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"> div content 5 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"> div content 6 </div>
 </div>
```

here, div's are equally(50%) sharing in both Mobile Horizontal/Vertical views..

But I want to get 3 div blocks in mobile Horizontal view & 2 blocks in Vertical view..

for this I tried below code also. But no Use...

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"> div content 1 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"> div content 2 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"> div content 3 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"> div content 4 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"> div content 5 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"> div content 6 </div>
 </div>
```

please check below jpg's for ref:

[image]
[image]

Please help me in this..

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the break point for the `col-sm-x` classes. In bootstraps CSS file, you will find a line like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, ....
```

Change the `768px` to wherever you want the break point where those classes to be overridden by the `col-xs-x`  classes.