# Bootstrap 3 col-xs and col-md Is not Responding

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid-system

I am having issues with my Col-xs and my col-md.

So before I continue ill explain my use.
Im Trying to create a user Form where they can enter their details and then enter a quantity for a piece of furniture. The furniture section is within a Tab-Content as there are separate sections within a house.

So id like for col-xs to span 2 columns, a column for label and one for the Quantity input, And then ill slowly increase by 2 columns, so sm will display, label, quantity, label quantity, and so on.

The col-sm and col-lg work Perfectly, but the col-xs and the col-md are not working, Its almost as if they are being skiped. Please help.

This is my code...

```html
 <div class="container">                   
                        
                            <h3>Houseold Inventory</h3>

                            <div class="tabbable">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#lounge" data-toggle="tab">Lounge</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#dinning" data-toggle="tab">Dinning Room</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#householdKitchen" data-toggle="tab">Kitchen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#bed" data-toggle="tab">Bed Room</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#study" data-toggle="tab">Study</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#householdGarden" data-toggle="tab">Garden</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#domestic" data-toggle="tab">Domestic</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#householdGarage" data-toggle="tab">Garage</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#householdGym" data-toggle="tab">Gym Equipment</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#householdMisc" data-toggle="tab">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#householdBoxes" data-toggle="tab">Boxes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#householdExtra" data-toggle="tab">Extras</a></li>
                                </ul> <!-- nav-tabs END-->

                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="lounge">
                                        <h4>Lounge</h4>

                                        <form role="form" class="form-inline">

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><label>Sleeper couch</label></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" />
             </div>
            <div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><label>Sleeper couch</label></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" />
             </div>
            <div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><label>Sleeper couch</label></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" />
             </div>
            <div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><label>Sleeper couch</label></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" />
             </div>
            <div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><label>Sleeper couch</label></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" />
             </div>
            <div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><label>Sleeper couch</label></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" />
             </div>
            <div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><label>Sleeper couch</label></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" />
             </div>
            <div>
            
                                            </div><!--end row-->
                                        </form>
                                    <div>
                                </div> <!--tab-content end-->
                            </div> <!--tabbable end-->
                        <!-- col-sm-6 END-->
                    
                </div>
```

I am very new to Bootstrap and Web layout, but criticism is welcome.

ps. Please Excuse the Layout issues i cannot figure out why the Code insert is doing this

pps. Check this Similer question For layout example :  [Unanswered Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469251/col-xs-not-working-when-mobile-is-orienting-between-horizontal-vertical-view-i)

ppss. Here is an image of my Mobile issue....
[image]

Comment: "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2" on each element (for example) certainly isn't right, you're misunderstanding how the grid is set up (which happens a lot until it "clicks" with you) - this is probably the best explanation about how to work with bs3's grid: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system

Comment: Hi there, Alright so I checked it out and I added the Empty div  :  ( <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div> ) But id did nothing, And evan without it it dosent change the xs or the md

Comment: For one thing, if the `col-md` and `col-lg` are the same (as an example), you only need to define `col-md`, `col-lg` will automatically use whatever was defined for `col-md`. So in places where you have `col-md-2 col-lg-2` you really only need `col-md-2`.

Comment: Also, this line has a typo: `<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>4/S Couch</label></div>`

Comment: Hi there Yes I have spoted that, also I have just edited my code, as it said col-xs-12 and it was ment to say col-xs-6, please review.  Also I fully understand what you mean by the md and the lg, I completely missed that thanks

Comment: What is the Full point of the ClearFix and the visible-xs ? When i used it the the col-xs-6 worked for all screen sizes insted of just for small

Comment: I just copied your code and pasted it at my machine.
It is working fine without the issue you mentioned above.
col-xs-* is working fine.
May be something wrong with your environment

Comment: How do you Mean ? I am developing in Visual Studio 2013, i dont this this would make a difference

Comment: Could it be the browser ? I'm using Chrome, But i don't see how that could be

Comment: I am also using Visual Studio 2013. it may be a conflict of some library in your project.
Try this: open a new project in visual studio 2013, create a new webform or html page, add bootstrap reference and copy your above mentioned code and paste it. 
Now run and there will be no issue.

Comment: Try this just to go deep and understand that there is nothing wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.
Some how my Bootstrap css file was not being read correctly, once I installed the **NuGet Package**, all was good and well, now my **xs** and **md** are working perfectly and as expected.

Thanks everyone who helped.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close in your initial layout. Only issue I saw was you duplicated a couple `col-md-*` classes on some of your `<div>` elements:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>4/S Couch</label></div>
```

Notice you have `col-md-2col-md-3` in there? That's not going to work. Also, on some of your elements, your `<label>`'s parent has `col-md-2` and the `<input>`'s parent has `col-md-2`, while others have `col-md-3` and `col-md-1`. That's not uniform and causes issues in alignment. I assumed that `col-md-3` and `col-md-1` was correct (if I'm wrong you can always change it to `col-md-2` and `col-md-2`) and edited your layout to the following:

```
<div class="container">                   

  <h3>Houseold Inventory</h3>

  <div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#lounge" data-toggle="tab">Lounge</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dinning" data-toggle="tab">Dinning Room</a></li>
      <li><a href="#householdKitchen" data-toggle="tab">Kitchen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#bed" data-toggle="tab">Bed Room</a></li>
      <li><a href="#study" data-toggle="tab">Study</a></li>
      <li><a href="#householdGarden" data-toggle="tab">Garden</a></li>
      <li><a href="#domestic" data-toggle="tab">Domestic</a></li>
      <li><a href="#householdGarage" data-toggle="tab">Garage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#householdGym" data-toggle="tab">Gym Equipment</a></li>
      <li><a href="#householdMisc" data-toggle="tab">Miscellaneous</a></li>
      <li><a href="#householdBoxes" data-toggle="tab">Boxes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#householdExtra" data-toggle="tab">Extras</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- nav-tabs END-->

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="lounge">
        <h4>Lounge</h4>

        <form role="form" class="form-inline">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Corner Piece</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end corner piece -->

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>4/S Couch</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end 4/S Couch -->

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>3/S Couch</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end 3/S Couch -->

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>2/S Couch</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end 2/S Couch -->

            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Armchairs</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end armchairs -->

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Recliner Chairs</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end recliner chairs -->

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Riempie Chairs</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end riempie chairs -->

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Sleeper Couch</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end sleeper couch -->

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Coffee Table</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end coffee table -->

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Occ.Table</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end occ table -->

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Hall Stand</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end hall stand -->

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><label>Hat Stand</label></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="QTY" style="width:60px;" type="text">
            </div><!-- end hat stand -->
          </div><!--end row-->


        </form>
        <div>
        </div> <!--tab-content end-->
      </div> <!--tabbable end-->
      <!-- col-sm-6 END-->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/8lLHupMIJM) to see this layout in action (just resize your browser).

Comment: Hi there Tim thanks for your input, i did not even notice my typo, thanks for that. So The layout is fine for col-sm and col-md, But the col-xs is not working. I have included an image of the Issue for mobile devices, i have also updated my code snippet, Please review.

Comment: Hmm... I can't actually replicate this issue in Bootply... Also, your code snippet is behaving that way because Bootstrap isn't included, you don't have a link to it. One thing you can try is putting your `<h4>Lounge</h4>` in it's own `<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><h4>Lounge</h4></div></div>` structure, so it won't be pressed against the left of the screen like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is a bit off. It should be more like this:

```
  <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">Corner Piece</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end corner piece -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">4/S Couch</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end 4/S Couch -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">My Label</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="QTY">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Take a look at [this functioning example](http://www.bootply.com/dc4Ru5bLKp)

HTH :)

Comment: Hi there Ted, I see that your Code is working Perfectly, But i have included an image of the issue i am having, Do you think it could be that it is within the tab-content and tab-panel ?

Comment: No...the bootply doesn't do that even at mobile size...see [this update with tabs](http://www.bootply.com/6geJK5xjnz). I think there's something else wrong in your structure